# Cannot access my website

Tags: nginx, debian, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

everyone! I'm linux-enthusiast and I have an issue with an nginx on debian VPS. Until recently I could access my static website but now I can't.

This is my `sites-available/example` where `example` is my username:

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
        server_name example.com ;
        root /var/www/example ;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html ;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 ;
        }
}
```

`sites-available/example` has s symbolic link in `sites-enabled`

My `nginx/error.log`:

```
2021/12/07 08:57:02 [notice] 7383#7383: signal process started
2021/12/07 09:22:00 [notice] 2195#2195: signal process started
```

Before `signal process started` I had 403 or 404 errors:

```
2021/12/05 17:53:05 [emerg] 12400#12400: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mail" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
2021/12/05 17:55:01 [emerg] 12415#12415: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mail" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
2021/12/05 18:02:33 [emerg] 12468#12468: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mail" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
2021/12/05 18:05:15 [error] 12522#12522: *1 directory index of "/var/www/mail/" is forbidden, client: 212.16.10.194, server: mail.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2021/12/05 18:07:45 [error] 12562#12562: *1 directory index of "/var/www/mail/" is forbidden, client: 212.16.10.194, server: mail.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

I even reinstalled nginx but I still have a problem with accessing to my website. What should I do or where should I search information to solve this issue?

`sudo ss -tnlp|grep :80` shows this:

`LISTEN    0         128                0.0.0.0:80               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("nginx",pid=2524,fd=6),("nginx",pid=2522,fd=6))`

`LISTEN    0         128                   [::]:80                  [::]:*        users:(("nginx",pid=2524,fd=7),("nginx",pid=2522,fd=7))`

Comment: The log messages are for a different server block than the one you are showing.

Comment: What files or logs should I show?

Comment: Entries related to `/var/www/example`, not `/var/www/mail`. Or the configuration for `/var/www/mail`. The actual error messages your client shows (not your interpretation of it) when you try to access the site could also be helpful.

Comment: After I removed ```sites-available/mail``` (with its symlink) there were no more 403 and 404 errors but there are ```signal process started```errors instead. Browser shows ```ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED``` error.

Comment: `connection refused` usually indicates that the service is not running.

Comment: I tried ```sudo systemctl start nginx``` and there were no errors but I still cannot access my website I also reloaded nginx with no errors either

Comment: Run `sudo ss -tnlp|grep :80` to check if something is listening on that port; check if your DNS entry resolves to the correct IP address; Confirm that you are trying to access the server via http and not https.

Comment: Output of ```sudo ss -tnlp | grep :80``` shows that 80 port is used by nginx if I am not mistaken

Comment: Please, edit all additional information into your question. It's much more readable there than in the comments.

Comment: I tried ```certbot --nginx``` and everything started working but browser cannot access ```styles.css``` with ```Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID``` error

Comment: That should be a new question. But before you ask it, inspect the certificate that your server delivers and check your configuration for the certificates that are used.

Comment: How should I do that? Is this question to be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments: nginx was only listening on port 80, but the OP was trying to access the site via https on port 443.

Running `certbot --nginx` added the necessary configuration to nginx to listen on port 443 as well.